# Can I split a comma separated value string into an array in the aggregate pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have data like this:

```
{tags: "a, b, c", ...}
```

Is it possible to create a pipeline stage that will split this into an array, something like this:

```
{tags: ["a", "b", "c"], ...}
```

in preparation for an unwind?

Failing that, what is the best way to do this? For legacy reasons I would prefer to leave the original data unchanged.

Comment: You mean the aggregation framework. No you cannot split strings. The only operator is `$substr` and that requires knowing the index values to "cut" at. MapReduce can use JavaScript to process the strings into an array. That's all you have available.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I keep on calling it that. Edited.

Comment: So I already told you how to solve it. `mapReduce` uses JavaScript `.split()`. Or would you prefer to accept a JIRA issue as an answer? [SERVER-6773](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6773). So which? A "solution" or something to wait around for?

Comment: @BlakesSeven - Both would be the normal protocol. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aggregation framwork lacks the operators to do this at present. There is a JIRA issue [SERVER-6773](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6773) which raises a need for a `$split` operator.

For now though, you can only do this with mapReduce. Something like:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        this.tags.split(",").forEach(function(tag) {
            emit(tag,someData);
        });
    },
    function(key,results) {
        // do something with the many results
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Or whatever.

In a nutshell, the JavaScript `.split()` is all there is to be able to seperate delimited strings in MongoDB server queries. So you can only really use a process that supports JavaScript processing.